# Negative margins to resize content and overlap absolute DIVs

Tags: html, css, user-interface, layout, margin

I have a DIV with two absolute DIVs inside, one on top and one on the bottom which together form a nice UI window.

Also inside the DIV is the actual content window which determines the height of the parent DIV. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ka9mkf9x/1/).

I'm trying to have it so the content is NOT confined to the inner content window, but so that it will instead fill the parent DIV. *As if the absolute DIVs for the UI and the inner content DIV are one DIV*. This will:

- overlap the top of the content with the top UI DIV
- overlap the bottom of the content with the bottom UI DIV
- emulate an even margin between the inner content window and the parent DIV

I was able to hard-code this with specific CSS (uncomment the commented out portion of the fiddle).

But what I couldn't do is figure out why `margin-bottom: -20px` does not apply -20px to the bottom of the margin and make the parent DIV 20 pixels shorter. I swear that has worked before. Not today.

Comment: _“why `margin-bottom: -20px` does not apply -20px to the bottom of the margin and make the parent DIV 20 pixels shorter”_ – because http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be stupid, but have you tried floating the inner DIV, that, from what I can think of, should take it outside of the normal flow of text, but still retain the text properties both the parent and inner DIV apply to it?

Comment: Far from it and precisely what was needed: http://jsfiddle.net/ka9mkf9x/3/. Thank you